# issue with regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

my file is

```
> A B C D unuse data  <begin> Addd as ss 1 My name is 2323 33 text 
> </end> 34344 no need
```

and my code is

```
StringBuilder mSb = new StringBuilder();
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"E:\check.txt");
           String line;

           while (sr.ReadLine() != null)
           {

               mSb.AppendLine(sr.ReadLine());

           }
string matc = new Regex(@"(<begin>)(\n?.*)*</end>)?").Match(mSb.ToString()).ToString();
```

here it reading all file , but i just want till 
if i am removing ?   from end , my program is crashing ..

Comment: Do you get an exception / error?

Comment: It's crashing? what exception are you getting?

Comment: crashing how, you mean throwing an exception? What is your actual question?

Comment: `ArgumentException: parsing "(<begin>)(\n?.*)*</end>)?" - Too many )'s.` - You have too many closing parens in your regex. Typo?

Comment: @RichardTowers  Hi  there i was miss one ( , thats why u getting error  (@"(<begin>)(\n?.*)*(</end>)")   if u use this , it will not give any error , just crash ..    any how i got answer ,   from BlackBear   , Thanks For ur response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you're looking for something like

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\check.txt");
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"(?s)<begin>.*?</end>").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The final code should look like this:

```
var text = System.IO.ReadAllText(@"E:\check.txt");
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"<begin>(.*?)</end>", RegexOptions.SingleLine);
string matc = match.Success ? match.Groups[1].value : null;
```

Hope this helps your quest.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the match before attempting to use it. Also use File.ReadAllText instead of dealing with the stream.

```
//var data = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\MyFile.txt")

string data = @"> A B C D unuse data  <begin> Addd as ss 1 My name is 2323 33 text
> </end> 34344 no need";

var mtch = Regex.Match(data, @"((<begin>)(.+?)(</end>))", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline );

if (mtch.Success)
   Console.WriteLine (mtch.Groups[0].Value);
else
   Console.WriteLine ("Failure to match");

/* Outputs

<begin> Addd as ss 1 My name is 2323 33 text
> </end>

*/
```